# Is the default value of a hidden element in html 1?

Tags: php, html

```
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>persistence demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Persistence Demo</h1>
    <form action = "" method = "post">
    <?php
        //load up variables
        $hdnCounter = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "hdnCounter");
        //increment the counters
        $hdnCounter++;
        print <<<HERE
            <fieldset>
                <input type = "text" name = "txtBoxCounter"/>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "hdnCounter" value = "$hdnCounter"/>
                <h3>The hidden value is $hdnCounter</h3>
                <input type = "submit" value = "click to increment counters"/>
HERE;
        ?>
                </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above program prints the hidden value as 1 on first page load. The hidden value increments by 1 with each form submission. Apparently, the counting part is done by the `$hdnCounter++` which we did not assign any number to start with.

`$hdnCounter++` is a part of the hidden element, so I'm thinking the default value of the hidden element must be 1 or how would we be able to increment it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to PHP, where empty variables are equal to 0.

Comment: what is the "empty" string anyway in the above program? aren't variables that are not assigned any value supposed to be null in php?

Comment: @TodoPertin: Type inferencing in PHP is a **big, bloody mess** that you're better off avoiding if possible.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that. Im such a noob.

Comment: By the way how does the above program start counting by $hdnCounter?

Comment: By "start counting" I mean there has to be an initial numerical value for $hdnCounter so that it is possible to increment it.

Comment: Because PHP infers the `NULL` returned by `filter_input()` as a 0. ***Big, bloody mess.***

Comment: ^ that is a question that shouldn't be asked though @TodoPertin if people see the question as being a good one, they will.